# Acknowledge based consume message from rabbitmq in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I am trying to consume message from rabbitmq in node js. It's consuming properly.
Here I am doing some operation (API call) during consuming message. Now **I want to acknowledge once api responded 200 status only** . Otherwise message will not deque. How can I do that ? Thanks in advance

```
let config = {
protocol: 'amqp',
hostname: '10.25.8.5',
username: '****',
password: '******'
};
amqp.connect(config, function(error0, connection) {
if (error0) {
    throw error0;
}
connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {throw error1;}

    var queue = 'test_queue';

    channel.assertQueue(queue, {
        durable: false
    });

    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages", queue);

    channel.consume(queue, function(msg) {


        let consumedData = msg.content.toString();

        // Other process by calling api .

        console.log(" [x] Received ", consumedData);

    }, {
        noAck: true
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Do you mean APIs do not return 200 you requeue the message?

Comment: If api returns 200 then particular message will deque . Otherwise not . Still remain in queue

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
channel.consume(queue, (msg) => {

  callAPI(data).then((result)=>{  
        if(result.statusCode == 200)
            channel.ack(msg);
  });

}, { noAck: false });
```

Base your api call, change result.statusCode section and also notice noAck: false to prevent automatic acknowledge the message